# Resource.Designer.cs has wrong values or mapped incorrectly

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, aapt

After merging my code, I have skipped merging the Resource file, at first there were missing references but I managed to make the resource file regenerate each build by adding the following into the csproj file.

```
<AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.Designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
<RootNamespace>Broadcast</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>Broadcast</AssemblyName>
```

The application throws an exception on the FindViewById() method, and claims that it "Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.EditText' to type 'Android.Widget.Button'."

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
Button btnSetURL = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSetURL);
```

While debugging I discovered that the ID taken from the Resource.Id.btnSetUrl was not the id of the Button, but the ID of an EditText. I tried rebuilding and cleaning rebooting with no progress, it keeps referencing the wrong ID.

If it matters, the EditText which is in the same XAML right before the Button, has the id of 2131493067
meanwhile the button's id is 2131493066

Comment: Did you try to edit your layout with AXML GUI editor? Not the text editor.

Comment: No, I only use the text editor. Would it make any difference?

Comment: delete the resource designer file as a whole and it will regenerate with everything properly